# Use intent to launch app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am implementing the intent to launch an application inside service. It's working fine when I pass other applications package names, but it's showing exception when I call the same package name where I have implemented the intent. It's showing like " have you declared it manifest or not ?". It's already declared in manifest.

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
nextIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.app1","com.example.app1.MainActivity"));
startActivity(nextIntent);
```

If I replace the package name , it's working fine. How to do it?

Comment: check whether you are using correct package name and the class name and also check the class is present in the package

Comment: Don't forget to mark answers as accepted; you have 7 questions and none of them has an answer mark as accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start the activity in the standard way:

```
Intent nextIntent = new Intent(context_reference, MainActivity.class);
nextIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
nextIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startActivity(nextIntent);
```

If you pass strings, you're screwed in case of a refactoring - if you forget to modify the string as well.